# Adding extra field in admin for custom user in Django 1.11

Tags: django, django-admin, django-custom-user

I have a custom user model which is subclassed by `AbstractUser` with an added custom field.

```
# model.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ADM = 'admin'
    MEMBER = 'member'
    ROLE_CH = ((ADM, 'Administrator'), (MEMBER, 'Member'))

    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CH, blank=True)
```

This model is also registered as the default auth model in `settings.py`

```
# settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "main.CustomUser"
```

Then in `admin.py` as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms), I create a custom form which extends `UserCreationForm` and then register it to the custom user.

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('role',)

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

However, it does not work as expected. The `Add User` form remains the default one i.e. only `username`, `password` and `password confirmation` fields are present. The `role` field does not appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) attribute instead of `add_form`:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**UPD**

First answer is correct only for `ModelAdmin` base class, since it doesn't have `add_form` attribute.

For `UserAdmin` you should update `add_fieldsets` attribute:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('role',),
        }),
    )

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

In this case you dont even required `add_form`.

Comment: Could you please expand on this? According to the documentation, `add_form` should be used for adding a user, and `form` was for editing the user. Also, I did try to change it but the form does not change.

Comment: @Demetris sorry I missed you are using `UserAdmin`. Check updated answer. You need to set `add_fieldsets` also.

Comment: `add_fieldsets` do not work for me, setting just `fieldsets` works. Did something change in between?

Comment: @seb probably you are not using `UserAdmin`.  add_fieldsets is only available for `UserAdmin` class.